# How to read STDOUT in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a command-line tool which, when invoked, asks the user to enter a password twice like this:

```
C:\>passwd.exe username
Please enter your password: 123456
Please repeat your password: 123456
DONE
C:\>
```

I'd like to write a Python script which covers this. Currently my script looks like:

```
from subprocess import Popen, STDOUT, PIPE
p = Popen("passwd.exe username", stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
print(p.stdout.readline())
```

I expected something like `Please enter your password:` to be printed but the process "hangs". What am I doiing wrong?

Comment: Your `passwd.exe` most likely uses `stderr` for its output instead

Comment: Many weird things can happend with password programs. They can  read from stdin or often directly from the console (tty on Unix-like) and they can write to stdout, stderr, or here again directly to console. As they are not intended to be used with redirected io, the defaults are generally the console.

Comment: Check out [getpass](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/getpass.html)